# How to pass a value to xsd:string RPC encoded SOAP xml parameter in java?

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, soapui

This is The XML used in WSDL which shows in SOAPUI.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bran="BDetail">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bran:sentIbBTyp soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <pBnCode xsi:type="xsd:string">234</pBnCode>
      </bran:sentIbBTyp>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I used this java code to pass values

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd",
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi",
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("bran", "BDetail");
SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();

SOAPElement soapElement = soapBody.addChildElement(
        "sentIbBTyp", "bran");
soapElement
        .setEncodingStyle("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");

SOAPElement elementBankCode = soapElement.addChildElement("pBnCode");
elementBankCode.setValue("234");
```

I got this error. Please help me...

```
SOAP error No Deserializer found to deserialize a ':pBnCode' using encoding style 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'. [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code may help. Check the other QName constructors and use the appropriate one.

Compare the generated XML with the working one in SOAP UI.

```
@Test
        public void test() throws Exception {
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd",
                    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi",
                    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("bran", "BDetail");
            SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();

            SOAPElement soapElement = soapBody.addChildElement(
                    "sentIbBTyp", "bran");

            soapElement
                    .setEncodingStyle("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
            SOAPElement elementBankCode = soapElement.addChildElement("pBnCode");
            // added missing attribute
            QName qname = new QName("xsi:type");
            elementBankCode.addAttribute(qname, "xsd:string");

            elementBankCode.setValue("234");

            soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        }
```

I hope this helps.